# Автогенерация документации с помощью скриптов

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!

Есть код программы, написанной на java... Нужно:
Автогенерация документации с помощью скрипта, выполнение тестов через скрипты(тестирование JUnit).

Вопрос касается литературы. Знатоки Java, подкиньте что-нибудь из литературы чтобы понять что нужно сделать и какими средствами. Примерами кода не брезгаю) Спасибо!

Comment: Особенно ставит в тупик "Автогенерация документации с помощью скрипта". Даже и не знаю где чего искать...

Comment: @Alerr, из литературы скорее всего будут только заметки в интернете и официальная документация (в которой всегда есть секция "getting started"). Документация называется Javadoc, генераторы без проблем найдутся по запросу javadoc generator.

Comment: Насчет автогенерации с помощью скриптов, поставил еле-еле javadoc, я все время качал не то что нужно( Кликнул Project->Generate Javadoc. Покликал next, что-то создалось(в папке проекта появилась папка doc, a в ней html странички.) это и есть автогенерация документации??? Я просто никогда этим не занимался и столкнулся впервые. Мне нужно к моему проекту написать документацию(Автогенерация документации с помощью скрипта), про какой скрипт тут говорится? Не понятно как связать Mavel и Javadoc, я читал, но понял так, что mavel чуть круче чем javadoc. Есть ресурс где про mavel обьясняют на пальцах

Comment: Вроде сделал документацию, спасибо. Осталась вторая часть - тест с использованием скриптов... Прочел много чего про JUnit. Понял что-то. Вопрос вот в чем, при чем тут скрипты?!

Answer (score 1):

Есть туча способов сгенерировать доки через исходники Java. `javadoc.exe` поставляется с JDK - лежит в каталоге `<JDK_HOME>/bin` - я уж не знаю как вы его там ищете...

Наиболее простой способ это генерация через любой IDE - Eclipse или IDEA вам в помощь. Можно тупо собрать доки через батничек или же собрать через `ant`:

```
 <target name="doc" depends="init" description="generate documentation">
 <javadoc sourcepath="${source.dir}" destdir="${doc.dir}"/>
</target>
```

Запуск через

```
ant doc
```

и вы получите искомое в каталоге `{doc.dir}`, надеюсь не надо объяснять что каталог должен быть продекларирован в свойствах `ant`

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/index.html) + [Javadoc Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/)

Comment: @Alerr, [должен быть](http://www.eclipse-blog.org/eclipse-ide/generating-javadoc-in-eclipse-ide.html) (только сначала надо будет установить [javadoc tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/javadoc-137458.html))

Comment: @Alerr, я наврал, похоже javadoc идет во всех комплектациях Java, т.е. уже должен быть уже у вас на компьютере.

Comment: если вам нужна автоматическая сборка, тестирование и генерация доков, ничего лучше мавена вы не найдете.
И да, утилита javadoc входит в состав jdk, смотрите паку \bin в директории jdk

Comment: Вроде бы есть в эклипсе, но он странно работает, я бы сказал, что не работает... Из всего что я прочел за 2 дня я знаю что есть mavel и ant. И они связаны с джавадоком. Там есть всякие xml файлы, они каждый из них там за что-то отвечает, они содержат пути к внешним обьектам...... Но я так и не понял, по шагам, как сделать автогенерацию документа с помощью скрипта. Может быть это из-за того, что я не представляю как вообще происходит автогенерация.

Comment: Установил jdk7.1, вроде такой был... изрыл поиском комп вдоль и поперек и не нашел javadoc.exe. Можете сказать где он по идее должен располагаться.

Comment: http://hkar.ru/qwmJ

Comment: Нету, я че только уже не поставил с их ораколовсого сайта... javadoc там нет. Качал вот отсюда: http://java.com/en/download/uninstallapplet.jsp    Это оно?
Нашел тут: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html#javadocdocuments маааленькую ссылочку, download... Перешел по ней и ничего не нашел. Сказано что javadoc может идти вместе с java 2 sdk, так его хз как скачать... Я уже подозреваю, что никто никогда не занимался документированием...

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

оффтоп: правильно написанный код, полностью покрытый тестами = лучшая документация